# Display random word from list

Tags: android, random

I am a beginner and I am making a an android app. My goal is to have the app randomly return a specific word from a list of word when a button is pressed. How should I go about doing this? Also, I am using eclipse and do not have much experience at all.

Comment: What kind of list? Can you show some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already mentioned in your question that you want to generate a word from a list of words, I assume that you already have the list prepared.

Use the following to generate a random number and then display the word corresponding to that index.

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100); // maximum value 100; you can give this as the maximum index in your list of words
```

***Note*** : do not use **Math.random** (it produces doubles, not integers)

**`import java.util.Random;`**

EDIT :

Assume that you have the list of words in a String array which contains 30 words.

```
String wordList[] = new String[30];
// enter the words in the wordList (if you have a String, use a Tokenizer to get the individual words and store them in wordList)
int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(30);
String wordToDisplay = wordList[randomInt];
```

Then, you can display wordToDisplay in your TextView by using `mTextView.setText(wordToDisplay);`

Comment: That just generates a random int. He asked for something else in the question.

Comment: Yeah so he can use the index of the random number and display the word corresponding to it.

Comment: @Tudor : Did that now. Thanks for the guidance. :)

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, this is my first app. But how exactly would I point this code to the list i want. And no, i have yet to make that list

Comment: @user1545666 : Edited my answer and added the code. Feel free to ask if you still have problems.

Comment: @swayam sorry to bother again, but I'm extremely inexperienced. Where exactly should this code go? Into strings.xml?

Comment: NOO!!! This code goes in your Activity.java. Are you not following any tutorials on how to create your first Android application ?If not, then I would really suggest you to do so. :)

Comment: @swayam I'm following the one on developer.android.com but it doesn't exactly cater to beginners :D

Comment: Maybe have a look at this then. http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html

Comment: @swayam thankyou! that one is much better. Also, Is there some syntax restrictions in the wordlist? It keeps telling me Syntax error on token, delete this token

Comment: @user1545666 : My friend I can't really help you unless you show me what you are trying and where you are getting the error.

Comment: @swayam So I am attempting to create the list of words. I assume they go inside of the brackets here

String wordList[] = new String[30];

So how do I input these words into the string. Say they were colors for example

Comment: wordList[0] = "red"; wordList[1] = "black";

Comment: Or if you want to do them at once then use String wordList[] = new String[] {"red", "black", "white", "..."};

Comment: Haha. :D It's an honour to serve! :)

Comment: No. It's an object of the Random class. just use Random randomGenerator = new Random();

Comment: @swayam umm it tells me that random cannot be resovled to a type. http://oi47.tinypic.com/6h26a8.jpg

Comment: Did you import java.util.Random ?

Comment: Happens, even to the best of us. Try using Cntrl+Shift+O to let eclispe organise your imports automatically. :)

Comment: @swayam yes sir it did. How would I go about making this work in response to a button click?

Comment: http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2011/04/android-simple-button-click-example.html

Comment: http://suvendugiri.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/android-using-button-click-event-with-example/

Comment: In short, define a Button in your layout. Make a reference to it in your java code. Define the onClickListener to perform actions when the button is clicked.

Comment: @swayam got my button created and labeled..not exactly sure where to go next

Comment: Button  mButton; inside onCreate() , put this code mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonIdInYourXML); mButton.setOnClickListener(onClick); close onCreate() and then private View.OnClickListener onClick= new View.OnClickListener() {
  // @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   
   //display the word
  }

 };

Comment: You know, by the rules of the site, there should be only one question per post. Hence, I cannot edit my answer to add this code also. If you have trouble, create another question related to it and send me the link here and I will surely answer it. :)